# Safari removes word-spacing using Typekit with optimizeLegibility

Tags: css, safari, text-rendering, kerning, typekit

I have a problem with Safari removing the space between words using Typekit font and text-rendering: optimizeLegibility in the css..

It works well in Chrome, so it's not a webkit issue. it works nice in Firefox as well.
The reason I want to use optimizeLegibility is because the kerning is horrible in the webkit browsers..

Any suggestions of what to do?

Edit:
[I've created a sample here](http://jsbin.com/opehiq/5/edit)
(It works well in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari 5.1.7(at least not in Windows))

As an alternative if someone could help me getting the start starting point in Firefox as in Chrome I can use lettering.js or something to kern it manually. I couldn't get it to work with text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;

**Edit :
Got this answer from Typekit:**

> I'm sorry you ran into this issue. Unfortunately, we've seen some of
>   these issues with: optimizeLegibility in Safari and Chrome. It seems
>   to be very random and affect certain fonts.
>
> I'm sorry to say but there isn't much we can do about this on our side
>   other than file a bug with Safari/Webkit.
>
> Could you tell me which font is showing the issue? Let me know and
>   we'll take it from there.

Hopefully they'll figure something out :)

**Edit: I've got more answers from Typekit now.**

> For the large headlines, you can simply change the setting with CSS.
>   That way you have the same starting poing in Firefox:
>
> text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
>
> This will change the text-rendering for Firefox and others. Then you
>   can kern with lettering.js.
>
> I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.

However I've already tried that, so I let them know, and unfortunately they couldn't help me any more with that issue.

I've attached an image of how it looks like in different browsers, all using Windows 7..

[image: Text-rendering with typekit on different browsers, using Abril Display]

Answer (score 0):

It actually is likely to be a webkit issue as webkits were actually invented by apple!

Rendering of fonts is down to the browser and even on the typekit website it seems all their fonts got rendered differently dependant on the browser.

A better alternative would be to use css3's new feature of @font-face and use whatever font you like without the need to use an external service.

The likelihood is that you can also render your text a lot better as you'll have more control over your content.

I'm not really sure where your problem lies, but maybe that alternative will help.

Extra info on webkits:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

If you look under origins it'll tell you about apple creating the webkit.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but the fonts I'd like to use needs to be purchased for that matter ;\ and I'd like to do it legally :P
As soon as I removes either Typekit or optimizeLegibility it works fine. and without optimizeLegibility the kerning looks horrible. I tried using letteringjs, but the same problem rises. In Webkit the starting point is without optimizeLegibility while in Firefox it is with, so if the kerning looks nice in Webkit it's too close in Firefox...

Comment: "It actually is likely to be a webkit issue as webkits were actually invented by apple!" Yes, but Chrome is built on WebKit as well. So if it doesn't happen in Chrome....

Comment: "A better alternative would be to use css3's new feature of `@font-face`" TypeKit is in fact using `@font-face` behind the scenes. I would be surprised if the problem guzh is experiencing went away with self-hosted `@font-face` fonts substituted for TypeKit fonts. Not that I want to talk up a competitor, but it seems improbable that this is their fault. Also, `@font-face` was invented way back in the 90s and was standardized in CSS 2, only to be removed in 2.1. So it isn't exactly "new" in CSS3.

Comment: @guzh: In that case you might want to implement the kerning using this website: http://typebutter.com/, hopefully that might be some use to you! Sorry my help isn't really accurate, it's a little hard to see the true issue because there is no live example.

Comment: @samayres1992 I've edited the question with a live example, did that last night. I'm pretty sure typebutter won't help as the starting point on the browsers are different (because optimizeLegibility is default in Firefox but not in the others), but I'll try

Comment: @samayres1992 the answer you got from typekit( text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;) fixed my issue in safari 5.1 in windows, thanks!